# Joining datasources by name in AX 2012 form

Tags: forms, datasource, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm trying to join multiple datasources in a grid I created.
The grid is in CaseDetail form and it uses same tables as some other groups on it.
Therefore I have to use joins based on datasources names and not on tables names.

There is InventTable(InventTableComplaints) - parent and EcoResProductTranslation(EcoResProductTranslationComplaints) - child.

What I'm trying to do is to add this code to the child datasource:

```
public void executeQuery()
{
    QueryBuildDataSource qbdsIT, qbdsERPTC;

    qbdsIT = InventTableComplaint_DS.queryBuildDataSource();
    qbdsERPTC = qbdsIT.addDataSource(tableNum(EcoResProductTranslation), "EcoResProductTranslationComplaint");

    qbdsERPTC.addLink(fieldNum(InventTable, Product), fieldNum(EcoResProductTranslation, Product));

    qbdsERPTC.joinMode( JoinMode::OuterJoin );
    qbdsERPTC.fetchMode( QueryFetchMode::One2One );

    super();
}
```

But it doesn't work.
Is it possible?

Comment: It looks like you're doing `addDataSource` to add another datasource, when it already exists on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not define the table relations in the `executeQuery` method, do so in the `init` method instead which is executed exactly once. If you defined the datasource in the form (using `InventTableComplaint` as `JoinSource` and with `OuterJoin` as `JoinMode`), you do not need to do it in `init` method either, but you may need to define the link if not provided as table relations:

```
public void init()
{
    qbdsIT = InventTableComplaint_DS.queryBuildDataSource();
    qbdsERPTC = EcoResProductTranslationComplaint_ds.queryBuildDataSource(); 
    qbdsERPTC.clearLinks();
    qbdsERPTC.addLink(fieldNum(InventTable, Product), fieldNum(EcoResProductTranslation, Product));
    super();
}
```

Beware that more than one record of may exist of `EcoResProductTranslation` for each `InventTable` (on for each language), so you may end out with "duplicates" of `InventTable` in the grid.

Comment: Finally I ended up with solution based on inserting translation into parent datasource (one above `InventTable`) and not joining anything in the form. But your solution gave me better understanding of where relations come from. Ad. different languages: you're right, I would also have to add `QueryBuildRange` to `qbdsERPTC`